# How to get or save the pitch listing in praat using scripting

Tags: scripting, praat

I am trying to use scripting in praat to either save or write to a file with the values given from using "Pitch Listing" under "Pitch". This is my code for the script so far:

```
selectObject: 1
View & Edit
editor: 1
    Select: 0.0, 10000
    Pitch listing
    p$ = Get pitch
    fileappend pitch123.txt 'p$'
```

This code only returns the mean for the sound file and I am wondering if there is a way to avoid getting small chunks of the file and getting the average pitch and instead being able to get the data given the way praat does it like so :

```
Time_s   F0_Hz
0.254558   125.982312
0.264558   127.975510
0.274558   123.010164
0.284558   120.761760
0.294558   119.652539
0.304558   118.916850
```

Even just being able to save the file that pops up from "Pitch Listing" would work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the new syntax (Praat >= 5.3.63), you can create a Pitch object and loop through the frames to get the Pitch value for that frame (by default, one frame every 10 msec).

```
writeFileLine: "./pitch_list.txt", "time,pitch"
selectObject: 1
To Pitch: 0, 75, 600
no_of_frames = Get number of frames

for frame from 1 to no_of_frames
    time = Get time from frame number: frame
    pitch = Get value in frame: frame, "Hertz"
    appendFileLine: "pitch_list.txt", "'time','pitch'"
endfor
```